# bootstrap 5 navbar offcanvas

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I got the code below from the official bootstrap 5 demos and for the life of me, can't figure out how to move the off-canvas menu from Left-to-Right. The documentation code to place the offcanvas-start and the demo code is completely different.

I am creating a landing page in Bootstrap 5, where the default menu should be replaced by an off-canvas menu with a close icon.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

      <!-- Static navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark" aria-label="Main navigation">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Offcanvas navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler p-0 border-0" type="button" id="navbarSideCollapse" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="navbar-collapse offcanvas-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
              <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Notifications</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Switch account</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Settings</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <form class="d-flex">
                <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>

      <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Offcanvas Navbar example</h1>
        <p>This example demonstrates using the offcanvas plugin with the navbar.</p>
      </div>

      <p>
        By default the navbar is show on the right side of the screen. You can show it on the left side instead by
        adding <code>.navmenu-fixed-left</code> to the <code>.navbar-offcanvas</code>.
      </p>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Static navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark" aria-label="Main navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Offcanvas navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler p-0 border-0" type="button" id="navbarSideCollapse" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

        <div class="navbar-collapse offcanvas-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Notifications</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Switch account</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Settings</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="d-flex">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Offcanvas Navbar example</h1>
      <p>This example demonstrates using the offcanvas plugin with the navbar.</p>
    </div>
    <p>
      By default the navbar is show on the right side of the screen. You can show it on the left side instead by adding <code>.navmenu-fixed-left</code> to the <code>.navbar-offcanvas</code>.
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- /container -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I made a snippet with a CDN link for the bootstrap (as a guess what you have in use) .  You may also consider adding a link to whatever you mean by "from the official bootstrap 5 demos "

Comment: I downloaded bootstrap 5 and  Then I copied in my own project. I want to solve my `offccanvas`

Comment: A comment just saying you downloaded does not help whereas an actual LINK to it might - note my answer may NOT match your source since I just guessed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need extra CSS and JS, just a tiny bit of inline styling. So all off canvas features and from left to right are in bootstrap itself. Here you go.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="zxx">

<head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="J. Stulemeijer" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <title>Offcanvas Component Navbar Example · Bootstrap v5.2.0 Beta1</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/starter-template/">    
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body> 
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4 fixed-top" id="navbar">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Bootstrap 5</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbarExample-expand-lg" aria-controls="offcanvasNavbarExample-expand-lg">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbarExample-expand-lg"></span>
                </button>
            <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start bg-dark" data-bs-hideresize="true" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasNavbarExample-expand-lg" aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarExample-expand-lg">
                <div class="offcanvas-header">
                    <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasLabel" style="color:white;">Bootstrap 5</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="offcanvas-body bg-dark">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Dropdown
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>                            
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Disabled</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="d-flex">
                        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
<div style="padding-top:5em">       
    <section class="container mb-4">
            <h2>Text to test body scrolling</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
            <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
            <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.</p>
            <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
            <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
            <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.</p>
            <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</p>
    </section>
</div>
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect, please edit your snippet and fix any errors

Answer (score 1):

I made a guess on the source of your example.
It has CSS specific to it and JavaScript specific to it.

Here I added the CSS in the snippet CSS block and the JavaScript in that block

Perhaps download instead of copy from the example site? FWIW I just used the browser to look into the actual source CSS in play here.

```js
(function () {
  'use strict'

  document.querySelector('#navbarSideCollapse').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector('.offcanvas-collapse').classList.toggle('open')
  })
})()
```

```css
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Prevent scroll on narrow devices */
}

body {
  padding-top: 56px;
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .offcanvas-collapse {
    position: fixed;
    top: 56px; /* Height of navbar */
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    overflow-y: auto;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #343a40;
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, visibility .3s ease-in-out;
  }
  .offcanvas-collapse.open {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.nav-scroller {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 2.75rem;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.nav-scroller .nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-top: -1px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.nav-underline .nav-link {
  padding-top: .75rem;
  padding-bottom: .75rem;
  font-size: .875rem;
  color: #6c757d;
}

.nav-underline .nav-link:hover {
  color: #007bff;
}

.nav-underline .active {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #343a40;
}

.text-white-50 { color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5); }

.bg-purple { background-color: #6f42c1; }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Static navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark" aria-label="Main navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Offcanvas navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler p-0 border-0" type="button" id="navbarSideCollapse" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

        <div class="navbar-collapse offcanvas-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Notifications</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Switch account</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Settings</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="d-flex">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Offcanvas Navbar example</h1>
      <p>This example demonstrates using the offcanvas plugin with the navbar.</p>
    </div>
    <p>
      By default the navbar is show on the right side of the screen. You can show it on the left side instead by adding <code>.navmenu-fixed-left</code> to the <code>.navbar-offcanvas</code>.
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- /container -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```